# Linear system of degree $d$ curves passing $m$ times through $P$ in the blow-up at $P$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, blowup

Given a point $P$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and a natural number $m$ we consider the linear system $\mathcal{L}$ of curves of degree $d$ passing $m$ times through $P$. If $H$ is the line class of the plane, this is a subsystem of $|dH|$.

Now denote by $\mathbb{F}_1$ the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at P, by $E$ the exceptional divisor and by $H'$ the pullback of $H$. It now seems to be the case that $\mathcal{L}$ transforms to the linear system $|dH' - mE|$. Why is that?

I see that the proper transform of a curve from $\mathcal{L}$ will intersect $E$ $m$-times, but why is that the same as the proper transform belonging to $|dH' - mE|$?

**update:** After reading the Chapter (4.3.1) in Shafarevich I understand better, but one question still remains: Why contains $|dH' - mE|$ elements at all? $Pic(\mathbb{F}_1) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ which, as far as I understand it, is generated by $H'$ and $E$, i.e. $H' = (1,0)$ and $E = (0,1)$. Then it seems to me, that the elements of $|dH' - mE|$ are the ones of the form $(d,-m)$. But how can an element of this form be effective?

My guess is, that I'm wrong as to which divisors are contained in $|dH'|$. If it were $(d,m) \in |dH'|$ there wouldn't be a problem. But how to explain that and would it then still be true that $H' = (1,0)$?

Comment: IIRC this is explained quite clearly in Shafarevich Volume 1, Chapter 4. The point is that if you pull back a local defining function for a curve in $\mathcal{L}$, you get a function that vanishes to order $m$ along $E$.

Comment: @Asal Beag Dubh: Thank you, indeed Chap. 4.3.1 is about exactly that and it answers my question. My mistake was that I thought the pullback of a divisor consists only of the birational transform as Shafarevich calls it. But of course for every time the divisor intersects $P$ there is a copy of $E$ added, which has to be subtracted again if we want to get the birational transform of $\mathcal{L}$.